# Verify if a value is a DBNull

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using the mySql connector with phpMyadmin and i try to verify if a value is a DBNull cause it make my project bug and I didn't succeed to find a way to verify it.

I tried:`if( aReader.GetString("ColumnName") != DBNull.value){...}` but it doesn't work.

I have this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.'

the code i made is :

```
MySqlDataReader aReader = aMySqlCommand.Command.ExecuteReader();
while(aReader.Read())
{
    aReader.GetString("columnName"); // there's the place where I get my error
}
```

thanks for you answer

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader.htm

Comment: Please proofread your post. BDNull != DBNull.

Comment: More specifically: [the IsDBNull method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_IsDBNull.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySqlDataReader has a method to check for null: `reader.IsDBNull(index)`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Check if value is null. do different things depending on if it's actually null or not.

```
if(Convert.IsDBNull(aReader["columnName"])) {
  //do things if null
} else {
  aReader.GetString("columnName");
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it worked well!